# GTK+ linux runtime library newbie

Tags: linux, gtk

Which package(s) that end-user need to run a simeple GTK+ app on Linux client machine?

I want end-user install package as low as possible

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question. What are you asking? If you are asking "what do I need ot tell the user to install", then the answer is it depends on the distribution but for those that split the runtime and development files, you need the runtime to run a prebuilt binary and the development files to build source code.

Comment: what I want is runtime to run builded binary (GTK+ binary app + minimum runtime to run my GTK+ binary app)

Answer (score 0):

Just install the GTK+ package your distribution provides. The binary package will come with all its dependencies, like cairo, glib, gdk, fontconfig, pango, gdk-pixbuf, etc.